# Convert columns into multiple rows per entry in R

Tags: r, excel, reshape

I have the following data:

```
word   Jan-2013  Feb-2013  Mar-2013
A      1         2         3 
B      5         2         4
```

I want to convert the multiple date columns into one, named date and add an additional column for the value.

```
word date       value
A    Jan-2013   1
A    Feb-2013   2
A    Mar-2013   3
B    Jan-2013   5
B    Feb-2013   2
B    Mar-2013   4
```

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: at least for the R case...

Comment: @krlmlr, I've added an Excel solution to make it less of a duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

#### Additional R options

In addition to Metrics's answer, here are two additional options for R (assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf"):

```
cbind(mydf[1], stack(mydf[-1]))

library(reshape)
melt(mydf, id.vars="word")
```

#### Excel option

I am not an Excel user, but since this question is tagged "Excel" as well, I would suggest the [Tableau Reshaper Excel add-on](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/addin-reshaping-data-excel).

For your example, it's pretty straightforward:

1. Go to the "Tableau" menu after installing the add-on and activating it.
2. Select the cells which contain the values you want to unstack. Click on OK.
3. View the result.

   [image: Basic "wide" to "long" reshaping with Tableau's Excel add-on]

Comment: +1: I didn't know that there is `reshape` in excel.

Comment: @Metrics, I don't actually even own a copy of Excel. Had to borrow a computer to write this answer. But, I had remembered reading something on the Tableau blog that was similar in concept to Hadley's "Tidy Data" paper, and they also mentioned this add-on. So, it was new for me too :-)

Comment: Answers are so much better with GIFs. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `reshape` from base R (df1 is your dataframe)

```
 reshape(df1,times=names(df1)[-1],timevar="date",varying=names(df1)[-1],v.names="value",new.row.names=1:6,ids=NULL,direction="long")
  word     date value
1    A Jan.2013     1
2    B Jan.2013     5
3    A Feb.2013     2
4    B Feb.2013     2
5    A Mar.2013     3
6    B Mar.2013     4
```

Comment: When did `reshape` in base R appear? I'm so much used to do this with `reshape2::melt`...

Comment: @krlmlr, `reshape` has been part of base R for as long as I've been using it. It's generally much faster than the current `melt` + `*cast` approaches, though I understand those are going to get some speed boosts of their own. Metrics, +1 for representing base R :-)